# Mongoose Schema: assigning a Typescript Interface to the schema

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, interface, schema

I want to use an interface to type a Mongoose Schema. Like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { Schema, Model, Document } = mongoose;

interface WordInterface extends Document {
    _id: string | null;
    wordType: WordTypes;
    text: string;
    verses: VerseFromTo[] | null;
    createdAt: number;
    modifiedAt: number;
    creator: string;
}

const wordSchema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: String },
    wordType: { type: Object as () => WordTypes, required: true },
    text: { type: String, required: true },
    verses: { type: Object as () => VerseFromTo[] },
    createdAt: { type: Number, required: true },
    modifiedAt: { type: Number, required: true },
    creator: { type: String, required: true }
});

const words: typeof Model<WordInterface> = mongoose.model('words', wordSchema);
```

But in this line, I get an error:

```
const emotions: typeof Model<WordInterface> = mongoose.model('emotions', emotionSchema);
                            ^               ^
```

There are two linting errors shown by the up-arrows beneath the line above. I'm a noob to typescript so I may be misunderstanding the syntax. The errors are both:
`TS1005: ',' expected.`

I can't work out what I've done wrong. I tried examples from these docs:

- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html
- https://thecodebarbarian.com/working-with-mongoose-in-typescript.html

I also tried typing the Schema but it won't work:

```
const wordSchema = new Schema<WordInterface>({
```

But it gave the following error:

```
TS2347: Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.
```

Stuck! Help very much appreciated ;)

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
```

Comment: I don't think your interface should extend Document by looking at this example
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html